# Prestashop - Admin Order Confirmation Mail Template modification

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to edit an order confirmation mail sent to admin. Can anyone guide me where to find that piece of code. I was able to change the User confirmation mail, but can't find the mail sent to admin.
Note: I am using a MailAlert module.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the body of a message can be done from the support of the backoffice in translations.
Location ---> Translations, (Translations of emails)

To change transactional aspects, it will depend a lot on what you want to change, but many changes can be solved from the file:

public_html / classes / Mail.php

For example,. if you want to modify the subject or similar things.

Answer (score 0):

It is `your-site/modules/mailalerts/mails/en/new_order.html`.